# why some methods has been never browsable from within an editor in WindowsPhone71 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

When I want to use the method `CheckAccess` in the class `Dispatcher`, I find that it is marked with `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)`, why is that? It's not fit to use in
the WindowsPhone7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by mistake? Or maybe someone was trying to hide it for some reason - maybe it was not originally meant to be exposed for some reason? Seems like the WPF version does not have that attribute, at least according to the documentation.

I would say - don't worry about it.

Someone also commented on it in the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=VS.95).aspx